# Mission Control Switching for windows

Tags: mac, dock, mission-control, spaces

**Introduction**

I am an avid user of Mission Control and use it to organize my work. Unlike most, however, I organize my work spaces by general topic, and not by application. For example I will frequently have `Google Chrome` open in 3 different workspaces at once (workspace 1 will be programming related, workspace 5 will be general work-related searches, and workspace 9 will have personal related windows).

**My Quesion**

For a specific application, how can I open a workspace that has a specific window of an application and move to the workspace at the same time? For example, if I am in workspace 3, and I look at the Dock that contains information about `Google Chrome`, it will look something like this:

[image]

In this example, `Files: Nature Biotechnology: nature.com` is in Workspace 5, while `automate-save-page-as/save_page_as ...` is in workspace one. **However** when I click on them and I am Workspace 3, it simply opens up the window *without bringing me to the workspace*. Is there a way to configure `Mission Control` to open the window *and* bring me to workspace the window is in?

Comment: That's funny because clicking on a particular window takes me to the Space the window is in. It's worked like that for as long as I can remember

Comment: The switching should work as you described. I see no reason it isn't behaving in the manner as it does on your system.

Comment: @NimeshNeema, can you elaborate? The way it is behaving on my system is **not** the way I want it to behave.

Comment: The way it is behaving on your system is **not** the way Mission Control generally behaves. The way you **intend** it to behave is the way it works without any additional configuration required.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will contact Apple

Answer (score 1):

Josh's answer here of adding `workspaces-auto-swoosh = ":true";`: solved the problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225294/282507

Answer (score 0):

As noted, how you want it to function is typically how it does function.

Make sure you have `When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application` checked in your mission control settings.

Comment: This did not solve the issue.